# SVG hover problem on multiple SVG element

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created 3 boxes and each box has an SVG image and just want to change SVG gradient colour to solid colour on hover on the particular box.

The first box is working well, but the second and third box is not working properly but when I am hovering on the first box the second and third box images are disappeared automatically.

```css
    .signup-as li a:hover .onhover stop{ stop-color: #fff !important;}
    .signup-as li a:hover .onhover2 stop{ stop-color: #fff !important;}
```

I have created a pen for this, please check the link - https://codepen.io/tsarkar/pen/MWWQevW

Comment: `id` attribute must be unique per document. Your path's `fill` is targeting the first `#linear-gradient`. Here I did click on your link, thing I don't usually do, and found that your question is very unlikely to help anyone in the future, since they will probably not be able to find this Q/A, but for next time note that you must include an [MCVE] **inside the question itself**, we should not have to leave stackoverflow.com to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use so many gradients since the gradient is the same. Use it only once. Also you are trying to change the values for the stop. In the next example I'm changing the `fill` for the `path`:

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 80px 0 0 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
li span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #42414b;
  padding: 15px 0 0 0;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 38px 0 0 0;
}
li a:hover {
  background: #06978a;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #06978a 0%, #253479 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #06978a 0%, #253479 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #06978a 0%, #253479 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(
      startColorstr="#06978a",
      endColorstr="#253479",
      GradientType=0
    );
}
li a:hover span {
  color: #fff;
}
li a:hover path {
  fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">
      <svg class="onhover" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="63.979" height="76.8" viewBox="0 0 63.979 76.8">
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="0.102" y1="1" x2="1" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#253479"/>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#06978a"/>
          </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path id="ic_Student" d="M669.319,606.387a1.135,1.135,0,0,0,1.134-1.136v-.711a13.289,13.289,0,0,0-9.693-12.771l-12.421-3.456-3.3-3.3v-4.878a15.432,15.432,0,0,0,8.392-10.481h1.515a4.167,4.167,0,0,0,4.16-4.165v-2.121a4.157,4.157,0,0,0-1.361-3.079V540.872h5.143v11.077a3.864,3.864,0,0,0,0,7.384v2.821a1.134,1.134,0,1,0,2.268,0v-2.821a3.864,3.864,0,0,0,0-7.384V540.872h1.134a1.136,1.136,0,0,0,0-2.272H610.634a1.136,1.136,0,0,0,0,2.272h8.546v2.279a1.134,1.134,0,1,0,2.269,0v-2.279H655.48V554.2H621.449v-5.747a1.134,1.134,0,1,0-2.269,0v11.832a4.158,4.158,0,0,0-1.361,3.08v2.12a4.168,4.168,0,0,0,4.16,4.166h1.515a15.429,15.429,0,0,0,8.391,10.481v4.877l-3.3,3.3-12.421,3.456a13.289,13.289,0,0,0-9.693,12.771v.71a1.134,1.134,0,1,0,2.269,0v-.71a11.01,11.01,0,0,1,8.031-10.581l7.48-2.081,4.2,13.336a1.145,1.145,0,0,0,.26.441l7.1,7.472h-15.58v-3.56a1.134,1.134,0,1,0-2.269,0v3.56h-9.226v-2.585a1.134,1.134,0,1,0-2.269,0v3.721a1.135,1.135,0,0,0,1.135,1.136h61.71a1.135,1.135,0,0,0,1.134-1.136v-3.721a1.134,1.134,0,1,0-2.269,0v2.585h-9.226v-3.56a1.134,1.134,0,1,0-2.269,0v3.56H641.11l7.1-7.472a1.14,1.14,0,0,0,.26-.441l4.2-13.336,7.481,2.082a11.009,11.009,0,0,1,8.03,10.581v.711A1.135,1.135,0,0,0,669.319,606.387Zm-5.294-49.155a1.591,1.591,0,1,1,1.588-1.591A1.591,1.591,0,0,1,664.026,557.232Zm-27.505,44.08h3.887l1.528,7.65-3.472,3.653-3.472-3.653Zm4.3-2.272h-4.712l-1.919-2.217,4.274-4.281,4.274,4.281Zm3.1-4.25-3.849-3.854,3.841-3.846,2.355,2.358Zm12.924-29.3a1.894,1.894,0,0,1-1.891,1.893h-1.134v-5.907h1.134a1.9,1.9,0,0,1,1.891,1.894Zm-1.361-6.251a4.152,4.152,0,0,0-.529-.035h-1.134v-2.726h1.664Zm-34.031-2.761h1.664V559.2h-1.135a4.154,4.154,0,0,0-.529.035Zm1.664,10.907h-1.135a1.9,1.9,0,0,1-1.891-1.894v-2.12a1.9,1.9,0,0,1,1.891-1.894h1.135Zm2.269-1.136v-9.771h26.166v9.771a13.083,13.083,0,1,1-26.166,0Zm13.083,15.375a15.292,15.292,0,0,0,4.311-.618v4.01l-4.311,4.317-4.311-4.317V581A15.271,15.271,0,0,0,638.464,581.62Zm-5.445,5.469,3.841,3.847-3.849,3.854-2.347-5.343Zm-6.577,4.18,2.266-.63,2.891,6.58a1.193,1.193,0,0,0,.063.122c.006.011.013.021.019.031s.033.05.051.074l.029.038.023.029,2.585,2.988-1.288,6.451-2.538-2.671Zm19.943,13.011-2.538,2.671L642.56,600.5l2.585-2.988c.008-.009.015-.019.023-.029l.03-.038c.018-.024.035-.049.05-.074s.014-.02.02-.032a1.271,1.271,0,0,0,.062-.122l2.891-6.58,2.266.63Z" transform="translate(-606.475 -538.6)" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
      </svg>
      <span>Student</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <svg class="onhover2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="94.971" height="76.153" viewBox="0 0 94.971 76.153">
        
        <path id="ic_Parent" d="M964.088,615.076a1.71,1.71,0,0,1,0-3.421h12.936a1.376,1.376,0,0,0,1.373-1.376V584.607c0-4.848-3.753-8.758-8.519-10.376l-7.42,10.374a2.951,2.951,0,0,1-4.7,0l-7.42-10.374c-4.694,1.593-8.52,5.45-8.52,10.376v25.673a1.377,1.377,0,0,0,1.373,1.376h12.937a1.71,1.71,0,0,1,0,3.421H943.187a4.8,4.8,0,0,1-4.786-4.8V597.841H916.678a4.065,4.065,0,0,1-4.057-4.065V574.187c0-6.391,6.077-11.575,13.531-11.592h6.87c6.8.015,12.282,4.281,13.341,9.667a19.489,19.489,0,0,1,9.679-2.317c1.835-.028,4.391,0,8.518,0a19.342,19.342,0,0,1,9.291,2.317c1.064-5.419,6.579-9.652,13.341-9.667h6.869c7.481.017,13.531,5.224,13.532,11.592v19.589a4.065,4.065,0,0,1-4.057,4.065H981.811v12.438a4.8,4.8,0,0,1-4.787,4.8Zm12.983-40.567a13.446,13.446,0,0,1,4.739,10.1v9.814h21.723a.645.645,0,0,0,.643-.645h0V574.187c0-3.3-2.441-6.143-5.945-7.434l-5.485,7.668a2.655,2.655,0,0,1-4.247,0l-5.485-7.668C979.651,567.994,977.072,570.664,977.072,574.51Zm-61.038-.322v19.589a.645.645,0,0,0,.643.645H938.4v-9.814a13.442,13.442,0,0,1,4.739-10.1c0-3.865-2.6-6.524-5.945-7.756l-5.485,7.668a2.653,2.653,0,0,1-4.246,0l-5.485-7.668C918.475,568.044,916.034,570.89,916.034,574.187Zm37.943-.734,6.129,8.569,6.13-8.57-.11-.012c-.18-.017-.361-.03-.542-.041-.081,0-.16-.011-.24-.014-.261-.012-.523-.02-.786-.02h-8.512C955.206,573.379,954.548,573.405,953.977,573.453Zm32.719-7.427,3.929,5.492,3.928-5.492c-.176-.007-.354-.011-.531-.011h-6.795C987.05,566.015,986.872,566.019,986.7,566.026Zm-61.037,0,3.928,5.492,3.929-5.492c-.176-.007-.354-.011-.531-.011h-6.795C926.012,566.015,925.835,566.019,925.659,566.026Zm21.888-14.518a12.559,12.559,0,1,1,12.559,12.585A12.585,12.585,0,0,1,947.547,551.508Zm3.414,0a9.145,9.145,0,1,0,9.145-9.164A9.164,9.164,0,0,0,950.961,551.508Zm29.677-2.577a9.987,9.987,0,1,1,9.987,10.008A10.009,10.009,0,0,1,980.637,548.932Zm3.414,0a6.574,6.574,0,1,0,6.574-6.586A6.587,6.587,0,0,0,984.051,548.932Zm-64.452,0a9.987,9.987,0,1,1,9.987,10.008A10.009,10.009,0,0,1,919.6,548.932Zm3.414,0a6.574,6.574,0,1,0,6.574-6.586A6.588,6.588,0,0,0,923.013,548.932Z" transform="translate(-912.621 -538.924)" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
      </svg>
      <span>Parent</span>
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="54.429" height="76.86" viewBox="0 0 54.429 76.86">
        
        <path id="ic_Educator" d="M1304.752,589.013v-6.875a.773.773,0,0,0-1.054-.722l-2.32.9-.01-.022-.08-.146a8.682,8.682,0,0,0-5.737-3.846l-8.117-1.479v-.642a12.412,12.412,0,0,0,5.951-8.339,4.963,4.963,0,0,0,3.945-4.854V550.753a7.769,7.769,0,0,0-5.542-7.456l-.5-.5a15.436,15.436,0,0,0-10.783-4.587,15.261,15.261,0,0,0-15.338,15.257v9.525a4.963,4.963,0,0,0,3.945,4.854,12.414,12.414,0,0,0,5.951,8.339v.642l-8.116,1.478a8.685,8.685,0,0,0-5.735,3.842l-.074.181-2.34-.912a.773.773,0,0,0-1.053.722v6.875a3.719,3.719,0,0,0-3.711,3.717v4.956a3.719,3.719,0,0,0,3.711,3.717v4.035a.775.775,0,0,0,.493.722l22.73,8.856a.772.772,0,0,0,.56,0l22.73-8.856a.775.775,0,0,0,.493-.722V601.4a3.719,3.719,0,0,0,3.711-3.717V592.73A3.719,3.719,0,0,0,1304.752,589.013Zm-15-9.245,5.356.975a6.2,6.2,0,0,1,3.905,2.5l-11.968,4.661Zm-12.109-2.447a12.307,12.307,0,0,0,7.212,0l-3.606,2.709Zm1.723,4.391-2.525,2.528-1.638-4.92.788-.143Zm7.14-2.534.788.143-1.638,4.921-2.525-2.528Zm7.113-14.053v-4.267a2.459,2.459,0,0,1,0,4.267Zm-24.74,0a2.459,2.459,0,0,1,0-4.267Zm0-7.555v.641a4.9,4.9,0,0,0-1.237.513v-5.089a12.94,12.94,0,0,1,12.807-12.947,12.666,12.666,0,0,1,8.972,3.743l1.091,1.094.333.082a5.294,5.294,0,0,1,4.012,5.146v7.971a4.855,4.855,0,0,0-1.237-.513v-.641a.774.774,0,0,0-.773-.775H1289.7a10.754,10.754,0,0,1-8.566-4.289l-.449-.6a.772.772,0,0,0-1.166-.083l-1.827,1.831a10.634,10.634,0,0,1-7.573,3.141h-.464A.774.774,0,0,0,1268.879,557.57Zm2.474,7.9v-6.253a13.084,13.084,0,0,0,8.085-3.81l.481-.482a13.242,13.242,0,0,0,9.778,4.349h1.448v6.2a9.9,9.9,0,1,1-19.792,0Zm-3.964,15.273,5.356-.975,2.707,8.135-11.971-4.663A6.2,6.2,0,0,1,1267.389,580.743Zm-10.881,16.944V592.73a1.239,1.239,0,0,1,1.237-1.239,3.717,3.717,0,0,1,0,7.435A1.239,1.239,0,0,1,1256.509,597.686Zm23.5,14.3-19.792-7.708v-3.4a6.187,6.187,0,0,0,0-11.34v-4.909l19.792,7.71Zm-3.673-23.734,4.91-4.919,4.91,4.918-4.91,1.913Zm25.939,16.024-19.792,7.709V592.338l19.792-7.71v4.909a6.187,6.187,0,0,0,0,11.34Zm3.711-6.587a1.239,1.239,0,0,1-1.237,1.239,3.717,3.717,0,0,1,0-7.435,1.239,1.239,0,0,1,1.237,1.239Z" transform="translate(-1254.034 -538.209)" fill="url(#linear-gradient)"/>
      </svg>
      <span>Educator</span>
    </a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: "You don't need to use so many gradients since the gradient is the same." That's wrong. They wanted to change the color only of the hovered element. If they were using only a single gradient and modifying this gradient, then all the elements would change color: https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/abbqQXJ